Can't access keyvault from backend appservice
I'm using Azure key vault to hold some sensitive data. i've given in access policy all permissions and the same for the dev app service that holds the dev backend. it works just fine locally and it access the data successfully. the problem when i pushed the update to the dev backend and tried it, the service was down and the whole backend was not working. i had to revert the changes but any idea what am i missing here? My application is hosted on Azure (app service) and the managed identity is activated.
here is the backend configuration:
in appSetting.json :
"your-key-vault-name":"SanedDevKeyVault",
in program.cs :
var keyVaultName = builder.Configuration["your-key-vault-name"]; var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net"; builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());. from azure side : i gave app service for the backend the access polic it needs : access policy
and i added the environment variable in the app service "your-key-vault-name":"SanedDevKeyVault", . it's working locally but not working when i try to run the application hosted on azure after adding those changes.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@dode what programming language/framework are you using for backend?

Can you share your code which you have tried?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya I'm using .net 6 (.net core api project) and it's hosted on azure. I configured the key vault from the backend. i'll edit the question and add the screenshots

@VivekVaibhavShandilya Also, the networking configuration for key vault is public access.

To access data from Key Vault you need to use specific client of the Key, Secret, Certificate.
Below given code worked for me.
I have created a Secret and fetching its value using controller in API
Controllers/Keyvault.cs:
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Dotnet_API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class KeyVault: ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<KeyVault> _logger;
        private readonly  SecretClient _secretClient;

        public KeyVault(ILogger<KeyVault> logger, SecretClient secretClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _secretClient = secretClient;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetSecret()
        {
            var secretName = "confidential";
            try
            {
                KeyVaultSecret secret = await _secretClient.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
                return Ok(new { SecretValue = secret.Value });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, new { Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var KeyVaultUrl = builder.Configuration["KeyVault:Url"];
var secret = builder.Services.AddSingleton(new SecretClient(new Uri(KeyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential()));

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "KeyVault": {
    "Url": "https://vivekkeyvault.vault.azure.net"
  }
}

To allow web app access in Key vault follow the steps:

Enable System assigned identity / Add User assigned identity



Create access policy in key vault and assign the required access


My secrete value :

OUTPUT:
Locally :
with swagger

without swagger

Azure :



So for variables like this in my code that expects the value of secrets defined in key vault var client_id = _configuration["HID:HIDClientId"].ToString() ?? ""; var client_secret = _configuration["HID:HIDSecretKey"].ToString() ?? ""; var grant_type = _configuration["HID:HIDGrantType"].ToString() ?? "";  i shouldn't leave it like this expects the _configuration to have its value. instead i should consume the key vault API you just defined right ?

Yes, This is How you can fetch the values of secret from key vault
